# Sorting an array that has been user generated has garbage data

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, cin

I have a program that an user inputs up to 50 integers. It then allows the user to search for the integer, shows where it is in the array once sorted, and the mean of all the elements.

Where I'm stuck is, the user generated input is...wrong. When I print out the array, it's incorrect values.

The code:

```
//inputSearch.cpp

//This program will allow the user to enter up to 50 integers.

//It will then allow the user to search the array they just created.

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 50;

void displayArray(int[],int);       // protoype to print out array  
void sortArray(int [], int);        // prototype to sort array function
int binarySearch(int[], int, int);  // prototype to binary search function
int getAverage(int[], int);         // prototype to get average of array

int main()
{
   int arrayList[SIZE];    //array...
   int searchFor=0;        // we're gonna search for this
   int found;

   int pos = 0;

   cout << "Please enter up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop): \n" ;
   cin  >> arrayList[pos];                                             // puts integers in array

   while (arrayList[pos] != -99)                                       // -99 to stop otherwise we'll be here all day
   {
      pos++;
      cout << "\nPlease input up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop)\n";
      cin >> arrayList[pos]; 
   }

   int value=pos;      //how many elements are entered

   sortArray(arrayList, SIZE);     // Sorts array

   cout << "Enter an integer to search for: ";
   cin >> searchFor;

   found = binarySearch(arrayList, SIZE, searchFor); 

   if (found == -1)
      cout << "The value " << searchFor << " is not in the list" << endl;
   else
   {
      cout << "The value " << searchFor << " is in position number "
         << found + 1 << " of the list" << endl; 
   }


   cout << "\n\n";
   displayArray(arrayList,value);

   cout << "\n\n";
   cout << "The mean of the values of the array is: " << getAverage(arrayList, value);
   cout << "\n\n";
   cout << "\n\n The array has " << value << " inputted elements\n\n";
   return 0;
}

void sortArray(int array[], int elems)
{
   bool swap;
   int temp;
   int bottom = elems - 1;      

   do
   {
      swap = false;
      for (int count = 0; count < bottom; count++)
      {
         if (array[count] > array[count+1])
         {             // the next three lines do a swap   
            temp = array[count];  
            array[count] = array[count+1];
            array[count+1] = temp;
            swap = true; // indicates that a swap occurred
         }
      }
      bottom--;     // bottom is decremented by 1 since each pass through
      // the array adds one more value that is set in order

   }while(swap != false);
   // loop repeats until a pass through the array with
   // no swaps occurs
}

int binarySearch(int array[],int numElems,int value) //function heading
{
   int first = 0;                  // First element of list
   int last = numElems - 1;        // last element of the list
   int middle;                    // variable containing the current 
   // middle value of the list

   while (first <= last)
   {
      middle = (first + last) / 2; 

      if (array[middle] == value)
         return middle;             // if value is in the middle, we are done

      else if (array[middle]>value)
         last = middle - 1;         // toss out the second remaining half of
      // the array and search the first 
      else
         first = middle + 1;        // toss out the first remaining half of
      // the array and search the second
   }

   return -1;                     // indicates that value is not in the array
}

void displayArray(int array[], int elems)    
{
   for (int count = 0; count < elems; count++)
   {
      cout << array[count] << "  " << endl;
   }
}

int getAverage (int array[], int size)
{  
   int sum = 0;   // holds the sum of all the numbers

   for (int pos = 0; pos < size; pos++)
      sum = sum + array[pos];  // sum now holds sum plus next element

   return (sum / size);  //returns the average
}
```

### The ouput I get for entering 100 and 100:

Please enter up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop):
100

Please input up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop)
100

Please input up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop)
-99
Enter an integer to search for: 100
The value 100 is in position number 36 of the list

-99

-1

The mean of the values of the array is: -50

The array has 2 input elements

---

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Suggest rethinking your input routine. Consider the case: `Please enter up to 50 integers (or -99 to stop): 
1 2 3 4 5 -99` It works, but the output is not what you want.

Comment: Is there a reason, why you don't use std::vector, std::sort and std::binary_search?

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing strange behavior due to the following problems:

1. You haven't initialized the array `arrayList`.
2. You are sorting the entire array instead of sorting only up to the number of entries the user entered.
3. You are using the entire array to search.

By changing

```
sortArray(arrayList, SIZE);     // Sorts array
```

to

```
sortArray(arrayList, value);     // Sorts array
```

and

```
found = binarySearch(arrayList, SIZE, searchFor);
```

to

```
found = binarySearch(arrayList, value, searchFor);
```

you will be able solve your problems.

You can use initialize the array using:

```
int arrayList[SIZE] = {0};
```

That won't change how your program works once you fix the use of `sortArray` and `binarySearch`.

Comment: binarySearch has the same problem as sortArray and earches the entire list rather than just the portion used. use `found = binarySearch(arrayList, value, searchFor); ` instead. Consider giving `value` a better name for readability.

Comment: Thanx! I also moved the part in main that says how many elements were inputted to the displayArray function to stay concurrent. I also renamed value to numOfElements for readability and to make more sense. Thanx everyone.